# If $f,g\in L^1$ does $fg\in L^1$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I was wondering : if $f,g$ are two function $L^1$ (or Riemann integrable function), is $fg$ necessarily $L^1$ (or Riemann integrable) ? I would say yes, but I can't prove it. Any idea ?

Comment: This is the case if $f$ or $g$ is bounded but, as @Surb showed, not generally.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**

What do you think if $$f(x)=g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x},$$ on $(0,1]$ ?

Comment: This is an answer. Not a hint.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I didn't make any proof of what I'm saying ! So it's a hint.

Comment: It's hard to give a hint here that $isn't$ a counter-example........+1